# How do I indicate a unique constraint in my Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, save, ruby-on-rails-5, unique-constraint

I'm using Rails 5.0.4 (and PostGres 9.5).  In my model I have a unique constraint across three columns

```
cindex=# \d user_notifications;
                               Table "public.user_notifications"
       Column       |  Type   |                            Modifiers
--------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer | not null default nextval('user_notifications_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id            | integer |
 crypto_currency_id | integer |
 price              | integer | not null
 buy                | boolean | not null
Indexes:
    "user_notifications_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "uk_user_notifications" UNIQUE, btree (user_id, crypto_currency_id, buy)
    "index_user_notifications_on_crypto_currency_id" btree (crypto_currency_id)
    "index_user_notifications_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

How do I indicate in my model that this unique constraint exists so that when I go and save my model

```
  if @user_notification.save
...
  else
    format.html { render action: "index" }
    puts "full messages: #{@user_notification.errors.full_messages}"
    format.json { render json: @user_notification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js { render json: { errors: @user_notification.errors, success: false }, content_type: 'application/json' }
  end
```

the proper error is saved indicating that a unique constraint has been violated?

Comment: The three columns are `buy`, `user_id` and `crypto_currency_id`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want uniqueness on `buy` with a combination of `user_id` and `crypto_currency_id`, then in your `UserNotification` model try the below

```
validates_uniqueness_of :buy, scope: [:user_id, :crypto_currency_id]
```

Comment: Why do I need to create the migration?  Per my table description, the unique constraint/index is already in the table, no?

Comment: @Dave But there is no unique index with a combination of all three. Isn't it?

Comment: @Dave Apologies, I see there is already a unique index. Updating my answer.

Comment: Hey I'm getting the error, "undefined method `validates_uniqueness_of' for UserNotification:Class".  Is this a version thing?  I'm using Rails 5.0.4.

Comment: @Dave How does you `UserNotification` model look like? Can you update the code in the question?